# She work(s) at the same place as you?

Tags: grammatical-number

Person 1: ...and we also work at the same place.

Person 2: She work(s) at the same place as you?

Person 1: Yes.

Should the "s" be included or not?

Comment: I work, you work, she works; we work, you work, they work. A more complete sentence would be "Does she work at the same place as you?"

Comment: "She work at the same place as you?" would certainly be understood but is definitely less correct.

Answer (score 1):

> Person 1: ...and we also work at the same place.
>
> Person 2: She work(s) at the same place as you?
>
> Person 1: Yes.

I work
You work
He/she/it works   (she works)
We work
You work
They work

"She" is 2nd person singular so:

**She works at the same place as you?**

Answer (score 0):

Definitely include the S. Removing the s, "She work at the same place as you" is improper and will only confuse. You can say: "We *work* at the same place", "She/He *works* at the same place", and "They *work* at the same place".